# Limits on Salesforce Chatter group & group members

Tags: chatter

Can anybody let me know if there is any limitation on the number of chatter groups & members to be added in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Max. Number of Chatter group = 30,000

And, members can be added unlimited in a group.

Refer [Chatter Limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_chatter.htm)